# how to reconnect peers with peerjs

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I'm using `peerjs` with `React` and `TypeScript`.
The two peers talk to each other for hours and sometimes disconnect from each other.

So I have two issues with that:

1. It takes too long until the "close" / "error" or any event sent after disconnection, how can I control it?
2. How should I reconnect last peer?

The way I use it:
import Peer, { DataConnection } from "peerjs";

```js
import Peer, { DataConnection } from "peerjs";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const address = '...'
    const peerRef = useRef<Peer>()
    const connRef = useRef<DataConnection>()

    useEffect(() => {
        peerRef.current = new Peer()
        connRef.current = peerRef.current.connect(address)
        connRef.current.on('data', (message) => console.log(message))
        connRef.current.on('close', () => {
            peerRef.current?.destroy()
            peerRef.current = new Peer()
            connRef.current = peerRef.current.connect(address)
        })

    }, [])

   retur null
}
```